# JMS Glassfish Connectors Not Created on Deploy

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I am trying to create a JMS Producer by following this tutorial:
[Oracle JMS Tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JMSProducer/JMSProducer.html)

However under the section :
*Start Glassfish Application Server and Deploy the application.* deployment of my generated *glassfish-resources.xml* runs fine and deployment is complete when looking at the logs, but under the Connectors my created resources are not listed. (only the default ones exist)

Here is what the tutorial expects-

[image: Expected Connectors]

Here is what my setup has after deployment-

[image: My Result After Deploy]

This is my Resource file, generated using netbeans.

[image: glassfish-resource.xml]

Apologies if this is an obvious one I am a little green to JMS.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue and any recommendations would be greatly appreciated thanks !

Comment: I have managed to resolve my issue by creating the connectors with the glass fish admin page, but this feels more of a work around than fixing the issue at hand so would still love to heard from those with more expertise.

Comment: I think you're a little late to the party. Glassfish 3.1.2 was release way back in early 2012 almost 10 years ago now. Your chances of getting much help are probably pretty low.

Comment: I think that is some oddity of netbeans, the Glass Fish Server is version 5.1